# curl error when using url string from string

Tags: json, bash, shell, curl

I'm now testing some restful APIs using bash shell script.
I want to read url from file then make a json data string with the url in file.
For the test, below codes work fine. It's not reading from file.

```
#!/bin/bash  
URL=http://test.com/test.jpg
curl -X POST \
-H "Content-Type:application/json" \
-H "accept:application/json" \
--data '{"url":"'"$URL"'"}' \
http://api.test.com/test
```

But, it returns some error when I'm using the codes like below.

```
#!/bin/bash  
FILE=./url.txt
cat $FILE | while read line; do 
echo $line # or whaterver you want to do with the $line variable
curl -X POST \
-H "Content-Type:application/json" \
-H "accept:application/json" \
--data '{"url":"'"$line"'"}' \
http://api.test.com/test
done
```

But, it returns error when I use the string from reading file. 
This is error message.

> > Illegal unquoted character ((CTRL-CHAR, code 13)): has to be escaped using backslash to be included in string value
> >      at [Source: org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteInputStream@27eb679c; line: 1, column: 237]

How to solve this issue?
Why it returns error when I use the string from file reading?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that your file is in dos format with `\n\r` line terminators.  Try running `dos2unix` on it to strip the `\r`s. Additionally, no need to `cat` the file, use redirection, like so

```
while read -r line; do 
echo $line # or whaterver you want to do with the $line variable
curl -X POST \
-H "Content-Type:application/json" \
-H "accept:application/json" \
--data '{"url":"'"$line"'"}' \
http://api.test.com/test
done < "$FILE"
```

Also, pass `-r` to `read` to prevent backslash escaping

Comment: @user2869281, just making sure, did you run `dos2unix` on the file before attempting?